# how can two people work remotely on the same repository in github?

Tags: git, github

so first I made a repository on github, then put the comands below in the console:

```
echo "# rotten-tomatoes" >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin https://github.com/ejample/file.git
git push -u origin main
```

and this pushes the project on github.

My partner clones the project with

```
git clone https://github.com/ejample/file.git
```

Now what's next? let's see, the project has Side A, Side B, Side C, Side D, he'd work in A and B and I in C and D, everytime we are done with a side we make a push but we also want to upgrade our local projects with the advances the other one is making, what's the best approach to do this? my guess is e.g

Once he cloned the project I start working on it, then when I'm done with side C I put these lines below

```
git checkout -b rick
git add .
git commit -m "side C completed"
git push origin rick
```

Then I want my partner to have the new changes in his local project, what should he do? I know he must use `git pull` but how? because when I use `git pull rick` the output is

```
fatal: 'rick' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

even though the branch rick exists. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might want to read this beginner article I've just posted: https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/

Answer (score 2):

You do not pull by branch name alone, but by remote name and branch name.

```
git pull origin rick
```

However, your partner cannot pull this branch at all, because pulling is into the current branch, and there is no local branch `rick` on your partner's machine. Instead, your partner will just say:

```
git fetch
```

Now your partner has a copy of the `rick` branch in the remote tracking branch `origin/rick`. That remote tracking branch is open to inspection. If there is a need to check out that branch (for example, to test what it does, or to modify it), then:

```
git checkout rick
```

This by default will neatly create a local `rick` based on `origin/rick`. From then on, it will be possible for either of you to

```
git checkout rick
git pull origin rick
```

Comment: when he uses git fetch it seems the cmd accepts the command but he doesnt see anything, then he tries git switch origin/rick and the output is "fatal: invalid reference: origin/rick" same with git checkout rick, it drops the error "error: pathspec 'rick' did not match any file(s) known to git"

Comment: Fixed, sorry about that. See edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

@matt's answer is I think a bit overcomplicated. Your partner (having cloned), needs just to do:

```
git checkout rick
git pull
```

The complicated bit emerges when you both change things - so you are both working on a branch at the same time, rather than handling over:

- Both you and your partner have to remember to push things to github (or whatever host to be honest). This is not automatic.
- You have to remember to do "git pull" on the branch before you start work - or you may not have the most up to date locally.
- "git pull" is technically equivalent to "git fetch && git merge origin". At best, this will be automatic but if you are making changes to the same bit of the same files, this can require manual intervention.
- similarly "git push" can fail because the other partner has updated in the meantime - you then need to do a pull. "git push -f" to force an update is a bit too easy - it can throw your partner's changes away.

For reason's like the above, it is often cleaner to use different branches and control when you merge.

Comment: No. Ex hypothesi, the rick branch was created after the partner cloned. Thus it is impossible to checkout rick, as it doesn't exist for the partner. That is what fetch fixes.

Comment: OK You'd need to fetch the first time, but then it is fairly straightforward.

Comment: That's right but the whole point of the question is that this is the first time.

Comment: Perhaps:) I didn't read it quite as unambiguous as that.

Comment: (If it is the first time, though, and the issue is that the co-working did a "git clone" prior to be branch being pushed, then all that is required is to do a "git fetch". It then does not matter if the coworker cloned before or after the push occured - a simple "git checkout rick" would suffice, with a "git pull" not being a bad idea just in case.